# set a random values in a field using UpdateMany in mongoose query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I wanted to know whether this is possible that while updating many documents using **UpdateMany** in mongoose I need to set any of the status value from **["pending", "settled"]** to a key called **payment_settlement** for different documents.

For better understanding I'm adding the route here:

```
router.post("/payment_settlement", (req, res, next) => {
    var ar = ["pending", "settled"];
    models.Payment.updateMany({ $set: { payment_settlement: ar[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)] } })
        .then(_ => {
            return funcs.sendSuccess(res, _);
        })
        .catch(next);
});
```

The above approach gave me the same result for all documents either "pending" or "settled".
My doubt is that MongoDB(Mongoose) computing random value once at the beginning, and using that single random value for all documents.

However, we can achieve this using **enum** in mongoose schema. But I need to update existing documents with random values.

Any ideas or discussion is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of mongodb are you using?

Comment: the version of MongoDB is 4.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using mongodb version 4.4.2 so you can use [Updates with Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) and [$rand](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/rand/) operator:

```
models.Payment.updateMany(
  {},
  [
    {
      $set: {
        payment_settlement: {
          $arrayElemAt: [
            ["pending", "settled"],
            { $round: { $rand: {} } }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
)
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZbhRrUEqTo3)

Or if your array have more than 2 elements, you can use [$multiply](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/multiply/) with [$rand](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/rand/):

```
models.Payment.updateMany(
  {},
  [
    {
      $set: {
        payment_settlement: {
          $arrayElemAt: [
            ["pending", "settled", "cancelled"],
            { $round: { $multiply: [{ $rand: {} }, 2] } }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
)
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/h8occJVDzdL)